# Why or How does FREETEXTTABLE give a rank value higher than others

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, freetext, freetexttable

There is a store procedure that uses FREETEXTTABLE twice on two tables and then merges the results and returns the top 50.

The problem is if I do a search on "Women of Brewster", the results returns "Confession of an ex doofus motha" with a rank of 143 from table A and second "Women of Brewster Place" with a rank of 102 from table B.

Is this because of the count? (Table A return results total is 2399. Table B return results total is 3445.)

Comment: Who are these Women of Brewster???

Comment: I'm guessing a movie and/or tv show series.

Comment: i would like to meet these Women.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer:

> Freetext ranking is based on the OKAPI
>   BM25 ranking formula. Each term in the
>   query is ranked, and the values are
>   summed. Freetext queries will add
>   words to the query via inflectional
>   generation (stemmed forms of the
>   original query terms); these words are
>   treated as separate terms with no
>   special weighting or relationship with
>   the words from which they were
>   generated. Synonyms generated from the
>   Thesaurus feature are treated as
>   separate, equally weighted terms.

The much longer, and far more complicated answer can be found on Microsoft's site, of course. For advanced mathematics, [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: MS's FREETEXTTABLE algorithm is terrible. It finds matches that aren't even remotely close.  I used it for looking for a query word "property" and it made hundreds of matches to records with no relationship (like numbers, single character entries, etc).

Comment: Use 

```
SELECT FT_TBL.Description  
    ,KEY_TBL.RANK  
FROM Production.ProductDescription AS FT_TBL   
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Production.ProductDescription,  
    Description,   
    'high level of performance') AS KEY_TBL  
ON FT_TBL.ProductDescriptionID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

To get result in sorted way and most relevant result on the top

Answer (score 1):

1) The noise file was limited to a few characters, meaning that the word "of" is now consider important.

2) The two tables results (count) do matter, since the smaller table will most likely be given a better weight value. This will skew the rank to be higher in a smaller table.

Josef's link to MSDN was great at figuring out how it computes the rank value.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
  
SELECT FT_TBL.Description  
    ,KEY_TBL.RANK  
FROM Production.ProductDescription AS FT_TBL   
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Production.ProductDescription,  
    Description,   
    'high level of performance') AS KEY_TBL  
ON FT_TBL.ProductDescriptionID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
ORDER BY RANK DESC;  
GO
```

Use this INNER JOIN approach to get the relevant results in sorted order.
Reference: [Azure SQL FREETEXABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/freetexttable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)