# FREETEXTTABLE Returning Incorrect Rank Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, freetexttable

I'm trying to fix a bug with a site search function and have isolated it down to an issue with the FREETEXTTABLE function.

I have a the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SiteContentForSearch INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(SiteContentForSearch, sSearchText, 'NFC' ) AS SearchResultTable 


ON dbo.SiteContentForSearch.liSearchID = SearchResultTable.[Key]
```

This is returning a rank of more than 0 for many of the rows which have 'NFC' present in the sSearchText column. However there is (at least) one row which it is returning a rank of o. It has the following text which as you can see contains NFC present a couple of times. Any idea's?

> Payments and Ticketing Contactless
>   smart cardsContactless smart card
>   technology is being employed
>   successfully in many areas. For
>   instance:Retailers are using
>   contactless smart card payments to
>   increase basket size and cut
>   queuesTransport operators are using
>   contactless smart cards (ITSO, Oyster
>   etc) to streamline backend processes
>   and improve the customer
>   experienceEvent and venue operators
>   are using RFID wristbands and
>   bracelets for effective and secure
>   ticketing and access controlNear field
>   communication (NFC) and mobile
>   paymentsWhen it comes to driving the
>   market for mobile payments and
>   ticketing, mobile phone technology
>   near field communications (NFC) could
>   be the answer. And as NFC does not
>   need special point-of-sale contactless
>   readers, NFC can be seamlessly
>   integrated with the existing
>   contactless infrastructure. But with
>   mass market adoption a few years away,
>   what should you do now?Working with
>   contactless smart cards, NFC and
>   mobile paymentsWe have been helping
>   clients improve their customers'
>   experience using RFID and mobile phone
>   technologies for a long time. As a
>   result, we can integrate all major
>   payment schemes. We can help
>   you:Understand your customers' user
>   journey to get the core applications
>   right such as payments and
>   ticketingInnovate, for instance using
>   RFID tags or NFC with digital signage
>   to personalise real-time customer
>   offersBuild and test NFC applications
>   within our NFC framework

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently having some FreeTextTable issues myself and the marked answer to this question:

[Why or How does FREETEXTTABLE give a rank value higher then others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210094/why-or-how-does-freetexttable-give-a-rank-value-higher-then-others)

which contains this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119%28SQL.90%29.aspx

explains how the FreeTextTable does its thing in maths. Particularly with reference to the OKAPI BM25 ranking formula.

Underneath the maths part is a section on issues with the ranking formula. Obviously its been 16 months since you asked this question but maybe this answer will help someone else with a similar problem. If you step through the problems and meta-problems with implementing the alogrithm you'll probably see where it could possibly be falling over.

HTH (someone...)

EDIT: Also the answer to this question:

[FREETEXTTABLE always has a rank of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097166/freetexttable-always-has-a-rank-of-0)

includes this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142524.aspx

Which is a more approachable summary of the info about how the ranking formula works that is contained in the previous link.