# ranking full text search results of several strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

I am getting some strings from a frontend and I would like to find all entries in a full text indexed view that match as many of these strings as possible. Example strings would be:

```
Bla di bladi
```

This can be translated into this query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM [Schema].[SomeFullTextIndexedView] 
WHERE CONTAINS (*, '"*bla*" OR "*di*" OR "*bladi*"')
```

which works fine. Let us say that for the sake of argument the query returns these results:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
bla  rte     
bla di   xxx
bladi    tttytyt     
bla di  bladi
```

What I would also like to do is introduce some kind of rank where rank is larger the more strings are matched. The rank is then used to sort the results descendigly:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Rank
bla di  bladi   3
bla di   xxx    2
bla  rte        1
bladi    tttytyt     

1
```

Is there anything in full text search that I could exploit for this? Thanks.

Comment: It is being a long time, but just in case of others are searching for this. You can't rank data with `CONTAINS` and `FREETEXT`. Actually, you should use `CONTAINSTABLE` or `CONTAINSTABLE`, look at [Limit Search Results with RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/limit-search-results-with-rank?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In common, you can use [FREETEXTTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) that returns RANK column:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM [Schema].[SomeFullTextIndexedView]  AS t 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE([Schema].[SomeFullTextIndexedView] , *, '"*bla*" OR "*di*" OR "*bladi*"') as k ON t.Id = k.[key]
ORDER BY k.[RANK] DESC
```

But in your example text strings are not relevant and it [always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097166/freetexttable-always-has-a-rank-of-0). Try it on real data.

Comment: Note: `ORDER BY RANK` not `KEY`

Comment: this works great. just curious how would I implement a fuzzy search in this scenario? Let us say the search string provided is bal but the database only contains the strings bla and bladi.

Comment: @csetzkorn MSSQL Server fulltext search is suitable for simple text search. I worked with it about a year, and I can say, that if you want to do something more complex than simple CONTAINS or FREETEXTTABLE, it will become very difficult. If you need to build a complex text search system, use something like ElasticSearch.

Comment: you should be using CONTAINSTABLE  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/freetexttable-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15
Unlike in the CONTAINS search condition where AND is a keyword, when used in freetext_string the word 'and' is considered a noise word, or stopword, and will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx)

> The table produced by CONTAINSTABLE includes a column named RANK. The
>   RANK column is a value (from 0 through 1000) for each row indicating
>   how well a row matched the selection criteria.

```
SELECT  *
FROM [Schema].[SomeFullTextIndexedView] t 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([Schema].[SomeFullTextIndexedView], ColumnToSearch, '"*bla*" OR "*di*" OR "*bladi*"') c
    ON t.ID = c.[KEY]
ORDER BY [RANK] DESC
```