# How to show data with have most word in search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

How can I show data with the most words in the search?
For example, I have a table like below:

| No | Word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b c e f g h j k l |
| 2 | a b c d e f g h i j k l |
| 3 | a b d f g h i k l |
| 4 | a c d e f h i k l |
| 5 | a b c d e f g h i j |

If I want to show data where "Word" have "a, b, c, d, e" it will show in order rec no 2,5,4,3,1.
I tried using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Word LIKE '%a%'
OR Word LIKE '%b%'
OR Word LIKE '%c%'
OR Word LIKE '%d%'
OR Word LIKE '%e%'
```

It works, but it cannot order by most words it has. It only shows the result with order 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: What does it means count by most words? 1) the text shoulb be the longest, so "abcde' is lower than 'abcde'. 2) the world with more occurences of a or b or c or d or e, so the 'abefg' is higher than 'bvrytmpk'?

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: Sorry, would you like to order by the length of `Word`? If so, you can try ordering by `LEN(Word)` if you're using sql server

Comment: This *might* be an important distinction, but what you have above are *not* words, that are characters. Will you *actually* be working with words? if so, then the problem could be quote different. For example, would you count the word table as both the words `table` and `able`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(Word LIKE '%a%', 1, 0)
                           + IIF(Word LIKE '%b%', 1, 0)
                           + IIF(Word LIKE '%c%', 1, 0)
                           + IIF(Word LIKE '%d%', 1, 0)
                           + IIF(Word LIKE '%e%', 1, 0)) ca(match_count)
WHERE  match_count > 0
ORDER  BY match_count DESC, 
            LEN(Word) ASC /*If two strings have the same number of matches prioritise the shorter one*/
```

If the table is large performance will be bad as it requires a full scan - but leading wildcards necessitate it anyway.

You can look at [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) to get better performance for this type of thing - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39076685/73226).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the existing query as a subquery and then order the results based on the **match_count** in descending order.

In this query your **match_count** is same for

> rec no 3 and 1

So it will show in order rec no 2,5,4,1,3 using below query.

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           (LEN(Word) - LEN(REPLACE(Word, 'a', ''))) +
           (LEN(Word) - LEN(REPLACE(Word, 'b', ''))) +
           (LEN(Word) - LEN(REPLACE(Word, 'c', ''))) +
           (LEN(Word) - LEN(REPLACE(Word, 'd', ''))) +
           (LEN(Word) - LEN(REPLACE(Word, 'e', ''))) AS match_count
    FROM your_table_name
    WHERE Word LIKE '%a%'
       OR Word LIKE '%b%'
       OR Word LIKE '%c%'
       OR Word LIKE '%d%'
       OR Word LIKE '%e%'
) AS subquery
ORDER BY match_count DESC;
```

Note: If there are two strings with the same number of matches, give preference to the shorter one.